# How to create an edge in Neo4j between two nodes matching two csv entries in neo4j?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, relationship, load-csv

Suppose I have the following table in a `csv`.

```
 elementID | groupID | sequence
     abc   |    A    |    0
     dcv   |    A    |    1
     asd   |    B    |    3
     ccc   |    B    |    2
     abc   |    B    |    4
```

I have already created the `Element` nodes in Neo4j (`sequence` is not an attribute of the nodes) having as attribute the key `elementID`.

From this `csv` I need to create a relationship from each `Element` node belonging to a group to another element belonging to the same group having the next `sequence` number.

With the data above I need to create a relationship from `abc` to `dcv` (labeled `A` for example), from `asd` to `abc` (labeled `B`) and from `ccc` to `asd` labeled `B` again.

I thought the query in this way:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///file.csv" AS row
WITH row
MATCH (from:Element {elementID : row.elementID})
MATCH (to:Element {...})
MERGE (from)-[r:row.groupID]->(t)
```

The problem is that I do not know how to `MATCH` the second node since in the graph I need the `nodeID` while with the current `row` variable I have only data of the `from` node.

How can I do it? Is there a way to use a second variable representing another entry in the `csv` to be used for the second `MATCH`?

In this last case, I would need to express conditions on it such as:

```
WHERE row2.sequence = row.sequence+1 AND row2.groupID = row.groupID
```

Comment: This type of CSV is not recommended. Instead use csv with columns like: `from, to, group`.

Comment: You can't match the second-row entry in this way.  If you can't make this like above format think of collect all element id for each group and sort them with a sequence number and Then create a relationship between elements within that list.

Comment: For dynamic relationship names, you can use `APOC Plugin`.

Comment: @Raj I do not choose the structure of the `csv` file. Just to let you know although I changed the table column names it is the same structure of the csv `stop_times.txt` file of the google_transit in the General Transit Feed Specification (GTFS) format.

Comment: They only thing I could do is create a new csv from this one and then import it in Cypher.

Comment: Okay. You can also load data from this CSV but the query will be complicated.

Comment: I mean create a new csv with other tools such as Python and Pandas, save it and just use that in Cypher, discarding the original one. Columns of the new one `first_el`, `second_el`, `groupID` for example.

Comment: Yeah, that would be easier